# request.FILES empty with Django Rest Framework FileUploadParser and Angular File upload

Tags: javascript, django, angularjs, django-rest-framework

I have an angular view that is uploading files via the template

```
Multiple
<input type="file" name="file" nv-file-select="" uploader="uploader" multiple  /><br/>

Single
<input type="file" name="file" nv-file-select="" uploader="uploader" />
```

and the controller using an angular upload library (https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload)

```
UploadController.$inject = ['$scope', 'FileUploader'];

 /**
 * @namespace UploadController
 */
 function UploadController($scope, FileUploader) {
   $scope.uploader = new FileUploader();
   $scope.uploader.url = 'api/v1/data/import/'
   $scope.uploader.method = 'PUT'

 };
```

On the server side the request is making it the right method in the View class

```
class FileUploadView(views.APIView):

   parser_classes = (FileUploadParser,)

   def put(self, request, format=None):

     file_obj = request.FILES['file']
     # ...
     # do some staff with uploaded file
     # ...
     return Response(status=204)
```

However the Dict that is created is empty

```
request.FILES['file']
(Pdb) *** django.utils.datastructures.MultiValueDictKeyError: "'file'"
```

It looks like there is parse exceptions built into the FileUploadParser that are not being run and that I am sending the right type of request over the wire. Why isnt there a way to tell why this request is not being parsed correctly? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all make sure that you know the difference between `request.files` and `request.FILES`. The former is for Django Rest Framework 2.x and the latter is for Django Rest Framework 3. As for the empty dict for some reason `FileUploadParser` was not parsing it correctly but switching the parser to `MultipartParser` did the trick. The `enctype` in the request was multipart so that might have something to do with it.